# How I want to display 2 child node in one firebaserecycleradapter?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I want to retrieve both the `Debt` node and the `Credit` node, as show in the following image:

[image]

Here is the code I tried:

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(MESSAGES_CHILD_Database);
mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Data,
        DataViewHolder>(
        Data.class,
        R.layout.activity_list_home,
        DataViewHolder.class,
        mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD_CREDIT)) {

    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(DataViewHolder viewHolder,
                                      Data data, int position) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
        viewHolder.nameTextView.setText(data.getName());
        viewHolder.dateTextView.setText(data.getDate());
        viewHolder.amountTextView.setText(data.getAmount());
        viewHolder.reasonTextView.setText(data.getReason());
        viewHolder.datePromiseTextView.setText(data.getDatePromise());

    }
};
```

currently i only can retrieve Credit without any error

Someone please help me!!

Comment: I removed the italics from your code. There is no reason for it to be styled that way. I also added the [tag:android] tag so your code is recognized as Java and highlighted appropriately. Please review Stack Overflow's [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Finally, I inlined your image, which you'll be able to do yourself once you earn enough reputation. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase recycler adapter only shows items from a single list/query at the moment. What you're trying to accomplish is not a supported feature.

Comment: Hello, is this supported now? example using one node like `Credit` that has the `id` of node `debit` as foriegn key. Are we able to retreive data and add it in recycleradapter?